# Limit the access of a function to once every 24 hours PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to limit the access of a function i've created to once every 24 hour based on the users IP address. I would also like the PHP script to delete the MySQL record if it's older than 24 hours.

If the user already has used the function within 24 hours, show them a message and prevent the script from continue running.

If the user already has used the function but 24 hours has passed since he used the function, delete the MySQL record and let the script continue running.

I'm lost and as you can see i am also missing some statements for deleting old records (-24 hours)..

Could anyone provide me with an example of how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Why do you want to delete the record?  I mean, you could, but you'll just be inserting it again.  If the record is newer than 24 hours, reject the action.  If it's older than 24 hours, update it to "now" and allow the function.

Comment: thank you for your reply, How to do it

Comment: Create a log, check the last timestamp is greater than 24 hours ago... we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a beginner I can not do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get client's IP address and store it with current date and time if the record doesn't exist.
2. Fetch the record and add 24 hours to its date and time value and check it with the current date and time every time the script is executed.
3. You need `if else` conditional statements to check if the 24 hours time is over or not. Based on that, you will control the execution of the function you want to.

I think I don't want to write much of theory. Here, I've written the pattern what the code looks like:

```
if(!$record_in_db) {
    // create record with the client's ip address and the current date and time
    // invoke the function you want - This is the code to trigger the function first time for the new IP address
} else {
    // fetch_record_from_db
    // add 24 hours to its date and time value
    // check it with current date and time

    $record_date_time = new DateTime('22-12-2016 22:45:20'); // this value should be fetched from database
    $record_date_time_by_24_hours = $record_date_time->modify('+1 day');
    $current_date_time = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('now')));
    $date_time_diff = $current_date_time->diff($record_date_time_by_24_hours);

    if($date_time_diff->invert == 0) {
        // Do something
    } else {
       // update the date and time of the record to NOW which is current date and time
       // invoke the function you want
    }
}
```

I can't write you the whole code. I could only give you some hints. You need to build the code from it. Hope I've given you right hints that could help you.

Comment: Thank you so much,
But unfortunately, I am a novice, I can not complete the code
I want ready code 
Thank you for helping me bro

Comment: What kind of function is that you would like to provide access to based on time?

Comment: I want same as this : https://linkninja.co/mzewwz/
Copy the link in your browser
Then go to for it
Then copy it again and go to for it again
It did not allow you to access the link again
but after 24 hours
This is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Oh. I got it bro. That's a nice idea.

Comment: I've written the code for what you're looking for. Since I had free time, spent some time with the code you're looking for. This is just some basic code. You can't expect much like advance stuff or like that with this code. Just check out this link. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rs8j-y5he

Comment: thank you bro
Yes, like him, But it does not work well
Because I talking about him Depends on the SQL
Wait professionals php

Comment: Why take computer ip.. I think It's supposed to take internet ip

Comment: If you refresh the page quickly You will know error ...He goes back again to the Hello, Welcome to our page!

Comment: I've just set manual ip's and also, I've set 10 seconds instead of 24 hours in the code just to test it out.

Comment: You can just download this zip from `phpfiddle`. I've uploaded all the required files to the folder. Here is the link. http://xfiddle.com/main/util/expzip.php?dir=e6e8cdc5

Comment: you are a Hero In php :) The code is already working.. thank you very very much bro :) - Perumal93

Comment: By the way, I've mentioned `+10 seconds` in the time. You need to make it `+1 day` to work with 24 hours as you asked.